# Unable to access images from outside folder in h:graphicimage tag

Tags: jsf

I want to access images from other project and i am giving value of

```
h:graphic value="/dmcmgs/vens/notification/images/image.png"
```

but it is appending the context path and it becomes something like

```
img src="/vens/web/dmcmgs/vens/notification/images/image.png"
```

how can I remove context path?

Comment: Accessing a resource of other projects requires the absolute URL of that specific resource.

Comment: @Tiny but that will work only for one url? like if i give for local host and that page works in other environment that will not work